# How to find the top number between a range given a value from a table using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

In my database I have the following table

[image: Database Table]

I'm using LINQ to get data from the database

```
 FlowCalcWeb.dbModelDataContext db1 = new FlowCalcWeb.dbModelDataContext();
  var EmergFlow = from p in db1.EmrgVents
                       where p.WettedArea == VarAtws
                       select new { p.VentingReq };
```

I want to get the top number between the range it fits, and retrieve **VentingReq**

Let's say my value is 55, it is between 50 and 60, the top number of this range in **WettedArea** is 60, so I want to retrieve from **VentingReq** 63200

Example 2, Given the number 47 as the **wettedArea**, I want retrieve from **VentingReq** 52700,

I was thinking I could use some linq, using the aggreate functcion, find the closest value and then, get the next one, but not really  sure how to do this since I'm really new on C# LAMBDA, LINQ, stuff,

Hope you can help me, Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
using (var db1 = new FlowCalcWeb.dbModelDataContext())
{
    var EmergFlow =
    (
        from p in db1.EmrgVents
        where p.WettedArea >= VarAtws
        orderby p.WettedArea
        select p.VentingReq
    ).Take(1);
}
```

Comment: nice!, very neat and easy solution, getting the values equal or greater than my value, then sorting, and then taking the first one, great solution thanks